# Can startServce() be invoked from any thread?

Tags: android

Most Android framework components are not thread safe—at least this is the assumption that I usually work with.

However, is it safe to invoke `startService()` from a background thread?

I came across a post from Dianne Hackborn who says that it is safe to call `sendBroadcast()` from any thread, so I want to assume that this is also true for `startService()` (http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/38a09b52de93f70a).

Can anyone with framework experience comment?

Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

I don't know the theory but I believe the answer is yes, and it is easy to try.  Just be sure that as always, if you are going to update anything on the UI, to put a Handler in your main thread - and then in the Service, send that Handler a Message containing the data to be put on the UI.

Comment: DJC, thanks for your answer, but this doesn't really address my question. Concerning updating the UI from a background thread: you're absolutely right. But my question is about starting an instance of android.app.Service from a background thread, not about updating the UI from a background thread.

Comment: Actually, I did :)  In your thread, do startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class)); and see what happens.  Simple as that.

Comment: This might work 99.99% of the time but it doesn't mean that it's thread-safe. I'll take a look a the Froyo source and see what I can find.

Comment: "Try it and see what happens" is a terrible approach to thread safety.