# Is it OK to call sendBroadcast() from another thread?

Tags: android

I have a service which creates a thread. This thread does some work and then calls `sendBroadcast()` on the `Service`. This means `sendBroadcast()` is called from the worker thread and not from the thread the service is running in.

Is this OK or should I make sure `sendBroadcast()` is called from the same thread as the `Service` (by using `Handler` and `Runnable`) ?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5024465/79455) on stackoverflow and [Dianne Hackborns post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/fK48x0Neuvo/CveT3lKboDgJ).

According to the post it should be fine. The reason I ask is because the post is 2 years old and maybe something has changed. Also I could not find anything about this in the Android documentation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is fine.  The Broadcast is handed to the Android OS and it is actually sent using OS threads so your thread that sends it does not matter.

Comment: How do you know? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Experience of having done it, the comments from Dianne Hackthorn and the documentation from the API where it says this call is synchronous: Broadcast the given intent to all interested BroadcastReceivers. This call is asynchronous; it returns immediately, and you will continue executing while the receivers are run. No results are propagated from receivers and receivers can not abort the broadcast. If you want to allow receivers to propagate results or abort the broadcast, you must send an ordered broadcast using sendOrderedBroadcast(Intent, String).

Comment: @Kaediil, your quote from the documentation only states it is OK to call it from the main application thread (not blocking), it does not state it is OK to call it from a background thread. If two different threads try to broadcast at the same time (by calling this method), will we have a potential problem with a race condition or not? Has it been implemented to be able to handle that case?

Answer (score 2):

You already got your answer but perhaps I can add some more.

It seems it's fine to call it from multiple threads. No matter what thread you call `sendBroadcast(...)` from, it's the onReceive method it's gonna handle it (as you probably know). And by default, it's working on the main/UI thread of your app. You can alter this behaviour though via `registerReceiver(...)`

It's like using a Messenger to have a client-sever connection. Remember all the messages, regardless of which thread they're sent from, handled in a single message queue which is consumed/looped over a single thread.